# Using people picker in infopath for approval workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, designer-workflow, people-picker, approval-process

I have created at 2010 approval workflow in sharepoint designer 2013. I have created a task form field "Approver" as a Person field type. During the single task behavior, I set this "Approver" field to the current item "Approver" value. I  then open InfoPath and insert it into infopath as a data field to be filled in. Finally, I update the list item fields based on what was submitted during the approval task.

Two problems occur. First, I can not get the people picker field to autopopulate in infopath even though I set its value during the task process. Second, when I fill out the fields on the user end, the data does not capture (i.e. I can submit the form, but it does not change the list field.)

Is there something wrong with my logic? + is there a better way to achieve what I want to do?

[image: Created Task form field]
Created task form field

[image: set task field to current item approver]

Set task field to current item

[image: infopath picture]

[image: infopath picture]

Infopath fields

[image: set current task item]
set current task item

Comment: You're talking about 2 problems occuring, but only mention 1. What is your 2nd problem?

Comment: Sorry, Second, when I fill out the fields on the user end, the data does not capture (i.e. I can submit the form, but it does not change the list field.)

Answer (score 0):

User/Group fields are populated by UserID and not Display Name or email address.  The xpath for the users within InfoPath will be different also.  You can use the UserProfileService.asmx web service to pull the user data and populate your InfoPath form with it and use the workflows with the user data pulled from the form correctly.  What you are asking is really not that straight forward either.  [Check this out](http://www.hishamqaddomi.ca/spg/index.php/sharepoint-2010/infopath-2010/65-checking-if-a-user-is-a-member-in-a-sharepoint-group-within-web-infopath-2010-forms), it might get you close to what you are trying to do.